# JDBC, servlets and strange "No operations allowed after connection closed"

Tags: mysql, servlets, jdbc

I have a servlet which put data to remote MySQL Database. From servlet I call post which run method, which connect to database, make operations on the table and close all resource. But, during prefom this, occur the "No operations allowed after connection closed. ". But if comment close methods on all resources, all works fine, and the database is update.

Below i present my code where I change the name of my object and error log:

```
public class MySqlManager {

Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("MySqlManager");
private Connection sqlConnection;

public Connection getConnenction() throws SQLException{
    sqlConnection = DriverManager.getConnection(DataConstants.dbUrl, DataConstants.dbName, DataConstants.password);
    return sqlConnection;
}

public MySqlManager() {
    DriverManager.setLogWriter(new PrintWriter(System.out));
}

public void putData(String value1, String value2, String value3) throws SQLException{
    Connection sqlConn = null; 
    Statement statement = null;
    ResultSet resultSet = null;
    PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;

    try {
        //register for MySQL driver
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").

        //get connection for data base      
        sqlConn = getConnenction();
        logger.info("Connect to database");

        int id;

        //create a statement which gets data from database  
        statement = sqlConn.createStatement();

        //if exist row in column sec_id, get id of this row
        String idQuery = "SELECT id FROM table1 WHERE sec_id = \'" + value3 + "\'";
        logger.info("query=" + idQuery);
        resultSet = statement.executeQuery(idQuery);

        if(resultSet.next()){
        //if row exist, update data in this row     

        id = resultSet.getInt("id");        
            preparedStatement = sqlConn.prepareStatement("UPDATE table1 SET col2 = ?, col2 = ?, col3 = ?, col4 = ? WHERE id = ?");
            preparedStatement.setString(1, "some_tekst");
            preparedStatement.setLong(2, 90854924897293);
            preparedStatement.setString(3, "some_tekst");
            preparedStatement.setString(4, "some_tekst"));
            preparedStatement.setInt(5, id);
            int i = preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
            logger.info("Update " + i + " record");
        }else{

            //if row not exist, insert data to table1
            preparedStatement = sqlConn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO table1 (col2, col3, col4, col5, col6, col7, col8) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
            preparedStatement.setString(1, "some_tekst");
            preparedStatement.setLong(2, 9146517234571);
            preparedStatement.setString(3, "some_tekst");
            preparedStatement.setString(4, "some_tekst");
            preparedStatement.setInt(5, 0);
            preparedStatement.setString(6, "some_tekst"));
            preparedStatement.setString(7, "some_tekst"));
            int i = preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
            logger.info("Insert " + i + " record");
        }        
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(MySqlManager.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(MySqlManager.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(MySqlManager.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(MySqlManager.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }finally{

          /*if I close all resources which has been defined above, I have an error:

            SQLState(S1000) vendor code(0)
                java.sql.SQLException: Operation not allowed after ResultSet closed

        if I comment code below, all works fine, and database is update
          */

            try { resultSet.close();} catch (Exception e) {}
            try { statement.close();} catch (Exception e) {}
            try { preparedStatement.close();} catch (Exception e) {}
            try { closeConnection();} catch (Exception e) {}
    }
    }

     public synchronized final void closeConnection() throws SQLException{
         sqlConnection.close();
         sqlConnection = null;
     }
```

}

```
lis 21, 2014 12:56:32 PM com.test.database.MySqlManager putData
INFO: Connect to database
lis 21, 2014 12:56:32 PM com.test.database.MySqlManager putData
SEVERE: null
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: No operations allowed after     connection closed.
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:386)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1014)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:988)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:974)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:919)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.throwConnectionClosedException(ConnectionImpl.java:1290)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.checkClosed(ConnectionImpl.java:1282)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createStatement(ConnectionImpl.java:2653)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createStatement(ConnectionImpl.java:2635)
at com.test.database.MySqlManager.putData(MySqlManager.java:33)
at com.test.database.SmackCcsClient.updateDB(SmackCcsClient.java:289)
at com.test.database.GCMNotification.doPost(GCMNotification.java:89)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:646)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:503)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:421)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1070)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:314)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

SQLState(08003) vendor code(0)
```

**EDIT:**

Error log when it occur during getConnection()

```
DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://mysql-testhost:3306/dbname")
trying sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver
*Driver.connect (jdbc:mysql://mysql-testhost:3306/dbname)
    trying com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
SQLState(S1000) vendor code(0)
java.sql.SQLException: Operation not allowed after ResultSet closed
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1074)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:988)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:974)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:919)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.checkClosed(ResultSetImpl.java:804)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.realClose(ResultSetImpl.java:7331)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeQuery(StatementImpl.java:1527)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.loadServerVariables(ConnectionImpl.java:4156)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.initializePropsFromServer(ConnectionImpl.java:3548)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2513)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2283)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:822)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:47)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:404)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:317)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:571)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:215)
    at com.test.database.MySqlManager.getConnenction(MySqlManager.java:8)
    at com.test.database.MySqlManager.putData(MySqlManager.java:52)
    at com.test.database.SmackCcsClient.updateDB(SmackCcsClient.java:289)
    at com.test.database.GCMNotification.doPost(GCMNotification.java:89)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:646)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:503)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:421)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1070)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
SQLState(S1000) vendor code(0)
java.sql.SQLException: Operation not allowed after ResultSet closed
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1074)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:988)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:974)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:919)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.checkClosed(ResultSetImpl.java:804)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.realClose(ResultSetImpl.java:7331)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.close(ResultSetImpl.java:923)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.realClose(StatementImpl.java:2590)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.close(StatementImpl.java:582)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.loadServerVariables(ConnectionImpl.java:4188)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.initializePropsFromServer(ConnectionImpl.java:3548)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2513)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2283)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:822)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:47)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:404)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:317)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:571)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:215)
    at com.test.database.MySqlManager.getConnenction(MySqlManager.java:8)
    at com.test.database.MySqlManager.putData(MySqlManager.java:52)
    at com.test.database.SmackCcsClient.updateDB(SmackCcsClient.java:289)
    at com.test.database.GCMNotification.doPost(GCMNotification.java:89)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:646)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:503)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:421)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1070)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
SQLState(S1000) vendor code(0)
java.sql.SQLException: Operation not allowed after ResultSet closed
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1074)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:988)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:974)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:919)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.checkClosed(ResultSetImpl.java:804)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.realClose(ResultSetImpl.java:7331)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.close(ResultSetImpl.java:923)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.realClose(StatementImpl.java:2590)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.close(StatementImpl.java:582)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.buildCollationMapping(ConnectionImpl.java:1076)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.initializePropsFromServer(ConnectionImpl.java:3556)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2513)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2283)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:822)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:47)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:404)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:317)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:571)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:215)
    at com.test.database.MySqlManager.getConnenction(MySqlManager.java:8)
    at com.test.database.MySqlManager.putData(MySqlManager.java:52)
    at com.test.database.SmackCcsClient.updateDB(SmackCcsClient.java:289)
    at com.test.database.GCMNotification.doPost(GCMNotification.java:89)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:646)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:503)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:421)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1070)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
SQLState(S1000) vendor code(0)
java.sql.SQLException: Operation not allowed after ResultSet closed
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1074)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:988)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:974)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:919)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.checkClosed(ResultSetImpl.java:804)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.realClose(ResultSetImpl.java:7331)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.close(ResultSetImpl.java:923)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.realClose(StatementImpl.java:2590)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.close(StatementImpl.java:582)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.isAutoCommitNonDefaultOnServer(ConnectionImpl.java:3798)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.initializePropsFromServer(ConnectionImpl.java:3644)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2513)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2283)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:822)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:47)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:404)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:317)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:571)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:215)
    at com.test.database.MySqlManager.getConnenction(MySqlManager.java:8)
    at com.test.database.MySqlManager.putData(MySqlManager.java:52)
    at com.test.database.SmackCcsClient.updateDB(SmackCcsClient.java:289)
    at com.test.database.GCMNotification.doPost(GCMNotification.java:89)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:646)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:503)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:421)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1070)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
getConnection returning com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

Comment: debug the code using breakpoints and verify where connection object is used after closing it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `static` modifier from `sqlConnection` object and `getConnection()` . it will work fine. The reason you get exception is this, by using `static` modifier you are creating a single connection object for all the objects of this class. If you close it once you are closing for all the servlets.

**EDIT:**

As discussed with david90 , the guy who asked this question, his problem was solved by  changing the version of MySQL driver. from 5.1.24 to  5.1.34

`Calling ResultSet.close() on an already closed ResultSet caused an SQLException.`

Problem Exists in MySQL driver `5.1.24`, while `5.1.34` fixed it.

`Calling ResultSet.close() on an already closed ResultSet caused an SQLException. While the exception was silently discarded, it did result in performance issues. This fix makes Connector/J comply with the Java specification that when a ResultSet object is already closed, application of the close method on it should be a no-op. (Bug #16722637, Bug #67318)`

Comment: I removed static modifier from sqlConnection object, but error still occur. I noticed, that sometimes error occur during perform DriverManager.getConnection()

Comment: I removed the static modifier from getConnection() function too. Even if I had forgot about this, netbeans warns me:)

Comment: @david90 remove this line  ` if (sqlConnection == null)` OR set `sqlConnection= null` after you close the connection .

Comment: I did it, but still doesn't work. Whether is it a problem when I have a tomcat on local server and mysql on remote server?

Comment: @david90 what is this `childrenResult` is it a global variable?  `if(childrenResult.next())` it should be `if(resultSet.next())` ... This exception has nothing to do with remote or local server.. It simply says you are trying to use a resultset object that has been closed already. So you have to check that you are not using any Resultset global variable .. And all local variables are closed and set to `null`

Comment: Yes, childrenResult this is the same object what resultSet, unfortunately I forgot change his name, sorry. I improved it

Comment: @david90 Now I have no idea .. Why it's not working. If you get a solution.. Then please tell me.

Comment: Hi! I think that I fixed this problem. This is strange, but I only changed the version of MySQL driver. Previously I had 5.1.24, now 5.1.34. So, What do You think about it?

Answer (score -1):

Your code isn't thread-safe. `sqlConnection` should be a local variable everywhere, and never an instance or static member. Ditto the Statement and ResultSet variables.

Comment: It seems that is not the case. At least I proposed similar things, but the original poster still had problems.

Comment: @GáborBakos False. There is not a word in your post about local variables or thread safety. The code in your deleted post *relies* on `sqlConnection` being a member variable, which is exactly what I have stated to be the problem.

Comment: It is already deleted, I used past tense. A quote: "I have not suggested to remove the static modifier. I would not make it a member either. Leaving it as a local variable might be a better design." It is true that I not mentioned thread safety though. Anyway, it does not work for the OP, so it is not so important.

Comment: @GáborBakos There is no evidence that the OP has ever tried using local variables only.